# Filtering "POSIXct" "POSIXt" column based on value and NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, posixct

I have a dataframe that looks more or less like this:

```
    tail(df)
    # A tibble: 6 x 3
      GEOGCD    OPER_DATE           TERM_DATE          
      <chr>     <dttm>              <dttm>             
    1 E05006867 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2019-03-31 00:00:00
    2 E05006868 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2019-03-31 00:00:00
    3 E05000066 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2018-05-02 00:00:00
    4 E05000067 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2018-05-02 00:00:00
    5 E05000068 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2018-05-02 00:00:00
    6 E05000064 2018-05-01 22:00:00 NA          
    
    str(df)
    tibble [52 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
     $ GEOGCD   : chr [1:52] "E05000064" "E05000065" "E05000066" "E05000067" ...
     $ OPER_DATE: POSIXct[1:52], format: "2009-01-01 00:00:00" "2009-01-01 00:00:00" "2009-01-01 00:00:00" ...
     $ TERM_DATE: POSIXct[1:52], format: "2018-05-02" "2018-05-02" "2018-05-02" ...
```

What I want to do is to select only those who have a TERM_DATE above 2018-12-31 OR are NA. Basically something like this:

```
3 E05000066 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2018-05-02 00:00:00
4 E05000067 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2018-05-02 00:00:00
5 E05000068 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2018-05-02 00:00:00
6 E05000064 2018-05-01 22:00:00 NA
```

I've tried different things, like this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)    
df%>%
filter(TERM_DATE> as.Date("2018-12-31"| is.na(TERM_DATE)))
```

But I keep on getting errors like the following:

> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
> x operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
> ℹ Input `..1` is `TERM_DATE > as.Date("2018-12-31" | is.na(TERM_DATE))`.

Can any of you understand why that might be and what I should do instead?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe ```filter(TERM_DATE> as.Date("2018-12-31") | is.na(TERM_DATE))```

Comment: I was trying so many different things and there's such a simple solution! It works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df%>%
  filter(TERM_DATE> as.POSIXct("2018-12-31") | is.na(TERM_DATE))
```

Output:

```
     GEOGCD           OPER_DATE  TERM_DATE
1 E05006867 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2019-03-31
2 E05006868 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2019-03-31
3 E05000064 2018-05-01 22:00:00       <NA>
```

The smart solution from **@StupidWolf** also works:

```
#Code 2
df%>%
  filter(TERM_DATE> as.Date("2018-12-31") | is.na(TERM_DATE))
```

Output:

```
     GEOGCD           OPER_DATE  TERM_DATE
1 E05006867 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2019-03-31
2 E05006868 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2019-03-31
3 E05000064 2018-05-01 22:00:00       <NA>
```

The output expected from OP can be reached using:

```
#Code 3
newdf <- df%>%
  filter(TERM_DATE< as.POSIXct("2018-12-31") | is.na(TERM_DATE))
```

Output:

```
     GEOGCD           OPER_DATE  TERM_DATE
1 E05000066 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2018-05-02
2 E05000067 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2018-05-02
3 E05000068 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2018-05-02
4 E05000064 2018-05-01 22:00:00       <NA>
```

Or using `as.Date()`. You need to change the comparison to `<`.

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thank you so much for the thorough answer.